# How to make People Editor look like Textbox?

Tags: sharepoint

I have three people picker controls on my aspx page. 
But the control size is not editable. I tried reducing its height, width but its not working.

How to make my people editor look like textbox.

Any Suggestions Appreciated.

Comment: Got the solution:

 <sharepoint:peopleeditor ID="Manager" Width="510px" Rows="1" runat="server"></sharepoint:peopleeditor>

To set height I used Rows="1"

Answer (score 1):

Add this class in your CSS, and update height and width as per your requirement.

```
div.ms-inputuserfield
{
    height: 24px;
    width: 151px;
}
```

This will update height and width of people picker.

PS: No need to apply this CSS class to your people picker control.

Thanks.